# Why does this process not execute whenever I type a discord command?

Tags: python, loops, discord, multiprocessing, bots

In the following code it’s a very simple discord bot which is supposed to start a loop when someone’s message starts with “.loop”. However with the command being typed the loop or the process does not start. What is the reasoning for this?

```
import discord
import random
import time
import multiprocessing
def boop():
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("I am looping.")

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
  if message.content.startswith(".loop"):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      time.sleep(1)
      p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=boop)
      p1.start()

client.run("bruh im not sharing token")
```

Comment: I've never seen `if __name__ == '__main__':` within a function like that, not sure if that's the problem or not but are you sure that it's returning `True`? Why does it need to be there?

Comment: @RandomDavis I've seen it, and I've seen it become a problem.. OP should definitely protect `client.run` from executing on import. Other than that, IDE's can mess with stdout, which can cause confusion with "my print statements aren't showing up from multiprocessing". Other than that this looks fine...

Comment: To clarify: `if __name__ == "__main__":` is absolutely necessary, but it's in the wrong place... The goal is to allow the file to be imported so that everything is defined in the child process, but nothing executes but the function passed as `target`.

Comment: @Aaron What are you trying to say here? In the multiprocessing docs, `if __name__ == "__main__":` is supposed to be put right before starting the process. How is it in the wrong place? The reason I'm confused is that if I just put the processes normally, it works. However, whenever I turn it into a discord command, it doesn't.

Comment: in this case it needs to prevent `client.run` from being called on import, so you don't get new duplicate clients in each subprocess. I'd bet that's not ideal (though I've not worked with discord.py, so I'm not 100% sure). preventing `client.run` in the child process will prevent further calls to `on_message` beyond the one that's intended

Comment: Oh, ok. But like what am I supposed to do to solve this inconvenience?